# One to many relationship in JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, orm, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

In one-to-many relationship in JDO between two objects A and B, should the object B be added to the collection of B's in A separately , when only B is persisted? or does this happen automatically?

for example if A has a field:

```
    @Persistent(mappedBy="a")
private List<B> bs= new ArrayList<B>();
```

and B has  a field
       A a;

Do I have to add objects of type B to the list in A manually or does this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List owns the relation so clearly you have to add the objects to the List, otherwise they won't be in the List. A List has ordering, and if the elements aren't added to the List how can a position for each element be known?